# Suppose $z$ and $w$ are non-zero complex numbers show how does $|z+w|=|z-w|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I do not see how $|z+w|=|z-w|$ because common sense tells me that $z+w$ and $z-w$ will not be equal to each other, thus moduli of the results will not be too.

Am I missing something? If I am correct, the identity is false?

Comment: The identity is clearly false, if you take $z=w$, for example.

Comment: Not even equal for reals which is a subset of the complex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I think if writing $z=a+bi,\,w=x+iy\;$, then

$$z+w=(a+x)+(b+y)i,\,z-w=(a-x)+(b-y)i\implies$$

$$ |z+w|=\sqrt{(a+x)^2+(b+y)^2}\,,\,\,|z-y|=\sqrt{(a-x)^2+(b-y)^2}$$

and I see the two above aren't equal. For example, take $\;z=i,\,\,w=i\;$

Answer (score 0):

The given relation is not an identity, as noted already. For example, for any $w\ne 0$ and $z =w$ $|z+w| \;=\; 2 |w| \ne |0| = |z-w|\,$.

If the question is under what conditions the equality holds true, that can be derived as follows:

$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{alignat}{2}
&& |z+w| && = |z-w| \\
\iff\quad && |z+w|^2 && = |z-w|^2 \\
\iff\quad && (z+w)(\bar z + \bar w) && = (z-w)(\bar z - \bar w) \\
\iff\quad && \cancel{z \bar z} + z \bar w + \bar z w + \bcancel{w \bar w} && = \cancel{z \bar z} - z \bar w - \bar z w + \bcancel{w \bar w} \\
\iff\quad && z \bar w + \bar z w && = 0 \\
\iff\quad && \operatorname{Re}(z \bar w) && = 0 \\
\end{alignat}
$$

For a fixed $w \ne 0$ the locus of $z$ is the perpendicular bisector of the segment $[-w,w]\,$, which is geometrically obvious since the condition $|z+w|=|z-w|$ means that the distances from point $z$ to the two points $\pm w$ are equal.